# Estou tendo um problema com codigo na solicitação do json gerado do php

Tags: php, json

arquivo consulta.php

```
<?php
     //header("Content-Type: application/json; charset-utf8");
     header('Content-Type:' . "text/plain");

    $baseDado = "teste";
    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "rafael";
    $password = "159";
    $ligacao = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$baseDado;host=$host", $user, $password);

    $motor = $ligacao->prepare("SELECT * FROM user");
    $motor->execute();

    if($motor->rowCount()==0){
            echo '<p>Sem Informações no banco de dado user</p>';
    }
    else
        {   
        foreach ($motor as $value) {
                    //$delete = $value['id_user'];
                    echo json_encode($value);
                    //echo '#ID '.$value['id_user'].'<br>';
                    //echo 'Nome '.$value['nome'].'<br>';
                    //echo 'Email '.$value['email'].'<br>';
                    //echo 'Senha '.$value['pwd'].'<br>';
                   // echo '<div>';
                   //     echo '<a href="delete.php?delete='.$delete.'">delete</a>';
                   // echo '</div>';
                   // echo '<hr>';
        }

    }


    $ligacao = null;
?>
```

Tenho informações de dado do json que foi gerado do php com o metodo, json_encode(),

```
{"id_user":"1","0":"1","email":"rafael@gmail.com","1":"rafael@gmail.com","nome":"rafael","2":"rafael","pwd":"rafael","3":"rafael"}{"id_user":"2","0":"2","email":"angela@gmail.com","1":"angela@gmail.com","nome":"angela","2":"angela","pwd":"123","3":"123"}{"id_user":"3","0":"3","email":"ricardo@gmail.com","1":"ricardo@gmail.com","nome":"ricardo","2":"ricardo","pwd":"000","3":"000"}{"id_user":"4","0":"4","email":"joao@gmail.com","1":"joao@gmail.com","nome":"joao","2":"joao","pwd":"159","3":"159"}{"id_user":"5","0":"5","email":"bruna@gmail.com","1":"bruna@gmail.com","nome":"bruna","2":"bruna","pwd":"bruna","3":"bruna"}{"id_user":"6","0":"6","email":"samsung@gmail.com","1":"samsung@gmail.com","nome":"samsung","2":"samsung","pwd":"159357","3":"159357"}
```

Quando faço a solicitações dos dados na apresentação da undefined na pagina do usuario
codigo em baixo do script

```
function bustarItem(){
    var items = "";
    var url = 'consulta.php';
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        datatype: 'json',
        beforeSend: function(resultado){
            $('.mensagem').html('Carregando');
        },
        success: function(resultado){
            for(var i = 0; i < resultado.length; i++){
                items += resultado[i].nome + '<br>';
            }
            $('.info').html(items);
        },
        fail: function(resultado){
            $('.mensagem').html('ERRO NO CARREGAMENTO');
        },
        complete: function(resultado){
            $('.mensagem').html('Tudo Pronto');
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Qual é o problema? você apresentou apenas os códigos.

Comment: na pagina em vez de aparece as informações que esta no banco de dado aparece undefined

Comment: Pode passar o código que está no arquivo **consulta.php** ?

Comment: acabei de atualizar, ver ai o arquivo, não ligar para os que estão comentado não

Comment: Esse código seria um sistema login?

Comment: Não esse codigo estou usando ele como estudo, só que o unico resultado que aparece pra me na pagina é undefined, o metodo que usso para busca informaçoes no banco de dado e PDO, so que ajax esta sendo o unico problema pra me ainda nao sei pq aparece undefined

Comment: Ok, vou testar o código aqui, 1 min.

Comment: blz testa ai pra ver se você coseguir descobri esse erro,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executei o seu código aqui isso foi o que eu fiz:

```
/
/index.js         #tem a função "bustarItems()"
/consulta.php     #retorna o suposto "JSON"
/index.html       #chama os arquivos e coloca o resultado nas divs
```

O seu problema é com o JSON que está sendo retornado. Repare.

```
//ASSIM DEVERIA SER O SEU FOREACH
$resultado = [];
foreach ($motor as $value) {
  $resultado[] = $value;
}
echo json_encode($resultado);
```

o que voce está fazendo é: A cada foreach é escrito um json na tela, **separadamente** assim não tem virgula entre eles, separando-os, logo da um erro e retorna undefined.

### Outra coisa

A função `success` do Ajax nunca é retornada(com `application/json` no consulta.php), só vai direto para o complete. Porque o Ajax espera um `application/json` vem um `application/json` porém uma resposta inválida, não é um JSON válido, deveria ter vírgulas entre cada objeto, algo do tipo:

```
[ #dentro de um array
    {"nome":"Fulaninho"},    #com virgula
    {"nome":"Fulaninha"}
]
```

mass..
se voce executar vai receber um erro no `JSON.parse()`

```
//no consulta.php, tem header("content-type: text/plain");
function bustarItem(){
    var items = "";
    var url = 'consulta.php';
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        datatype: 'json',
        beforeSend: function(resultado){
            $('.mensagem').html('Carregando');
        },
        success: function(resultado){
        },
        fail: function(resultado){
            $('.mensagem').html('ERRO NO CARREGAMENTO');
        },
        complete: function(response){
            $('.mensagem').html('Tudo Pronto');

            var resultado = response.responseText
            console.log(JSON.parse(resultado)); //ERRO <<<<<
            for(var i = 0; i < resultado.length; i++){
                items += resultado[i].nome + '<br>';
            }
            $('.info').html(items);
        }
    })
}    
bustarItem();
```

Como eu disse, erro na `consulta.php`, faça conforme eu fiz.

### Dica:

No consulta.php, ao inves de um foreach, poderia colocar algo do tipo.

```
$resultado = $resultado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
echo json_encode($resultado);
```

Percebe que no seu JSON está valores repetidos com chaves diferentes, olha:

```
    id         id       email                    email
{"id_user":"2","0":"2","email":"angela@gmail.com","1":"angela@gmail.com"}
```

Comment: nossa mano flw mesmo, fiz realmente deu certo